# Get all object from a "group" in PHP from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to catch all objects in PHP from a JSON array, I need all the objects that will appear under ["Elements"]. So how would this be possible if I:

1.) Don't know the "name" of the object and don't know the content inside it.
2.) What I would like to achieve is to get the first objects value inside Elements, and then get the "content" inside of it, regardless of the names (there could be multiple objects)

Here is a var_dump of the JSON:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["Canvas"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
        ["Elements"]=>
          object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
            ["textHolder2"]=>
              object(stdClass)#19 (1) {
                ["textContent"]=>
                  string(12) "Text to edit"
              }
            ["textHolder1"]=>
              object(stdClass)#20 (1) {
                ["textContent"]=>
                  string(12) "Text to edit"
              }
          }
      }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
$json = json_decode( $input, true );
$elems = $json['canvas']['Elements'];

foreach( $elems as $key => $value ) {
  echo "{$key} is an array/object:\n";
  echo var_dump( $value );
}
```

You could use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if you need to know what keys are inside `$value` or you could another foreach loop, but I am assuming you will have at least some clue what keys could be in `$value`.